# Disable Magento Category from the Database

Tags: magento

I want to enable or disable a category from the database. The goal is to create a cronjob that periodically activates a new category and disables obsolete categories. I've searched in the database, but I don´t see anything.

Help please.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Look at `eav_attribute` and find the `attribute_id` thats associated with `is_active` and then look for the `attribute_id` value in `catalog_category_entity_int` there you'll find a `value` boolean.

Comment: hi, i need help. I use this for modify the attribute Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load(id)->setIsActive(1), but the category change in the frontend and i don´t see the changes in the admin panel. don´t modify the attribute in catalog_category_entity_int. anr blocked this attribute?

Comment: Be sure your to clear your cache and rebuild indexes if your using a flat catalog.  That magic get/set should be disable/enabling the attribute.

Comment: I reindex all and flush cache but don´t work. After execute  Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load(id)->setIsActive(0);  look the table catalog_category_entity_int and i see this: value_id=160, entity_type_id=3, attribute_id=34, store_id=0, entity_id=23, value=1. But later execution in my store i don´t see the disabled category and since admin panel i can look the category active ¿?¿?¿? very strange

Comment: On Magento (ver. 1.6.2.0), attribute_id is 36 in catalog_category_entity_int to enable/disable category